# Co-finite and Co-countable topologies are not normal

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

I’ve been investigating these two topologies on $\mathbb R$ and believe that they are both not normal as not every 2  disjoint closed sets have disjoint open neighbourhoods but I’m struggling to find an example that shows this (a counter example to the definition of normal).

I believe the same example will work for both cofinite and cocountable topology.

Can anyone help please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take for example the closed subsets $A=\{0\}$ and $B=\{1\}$. Suppose you have neighborhoods $U$ of $0$ and $V$ of $1$ such that $U\cap V=\varnothing$. That would mean that $U^c\cup V^c=\mathbb{R}$. But $U^c$ and $V^c$ are finite (countable) in the co-finite (co-countable) topology, leading to a contradiction. So that would be a counterexample.

Comment: Thank you for the response @saul ilo. This is the example that I originally thought of but couldn't justify that A and B were part of the topology since $\mathbb{R}$ \ A is an uncountable, infinite set. The same idea for B. Could you explain this part please?

Comment: We need $A$ and $B$ to be closed subspaces, not open ones, because the definition of normal spaces says that you can separate any two disjoint closed subspaces. The closed subspaces in the cofinite topology are the finite sets (and the whole space $X$), and they are the countable sets in the co-countable topology.

Comment: I see. I was thinking that they still had to be part of the topology. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Every two non-empty open sets have non-empty intersection, therefore any two disjoint non-empty closed sets are instances that disprove normality.